# Change logging in the Mule

Tags: mule

I have a Mule project that I want to run from AnypointStudio. It uses the default log4j2.xml, but I want to change that.

According to the documentation (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Logging+in+Mule), it is posible to put another log4j2.xml file on the classpath, but that does not work.

In the "run configuration" of Anypoint I added a classpath. In that classpath folder I added another log4j2.xml file, but that is ignored by the Mule, although it sees another file in that folder.

How do I add an log4j2.xml file?

Comment: Can you can put it in src/main/resources? HTH.

Comment: Yes, in src/main/resources works, but when I put it there, it also gets deployed on the server. The server has its own log4j2.xml

Answer (score 2):

Put your `log4j2.xml` config in `src/test/resources`, that way it won't be packaged in the app but will be available in Studio, when you launch the app.

Comment: You can also use log4j2-test.xml and it will supercede log4j2.xml.  That way you can use different logging when running tests than when running in an environment.

Comment: Neither log4j2.xml nor log4j2-test in src/test/resources works for me. It is a maven build project, does that makes any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. Was `src/test/resources` selected as a source folder in Studio?

Comment: It is a source folder. When I look in the `.mule` folder, there is no log4j-test.xml in the classes folder, but it is in the `src/test/resources`.